# How can I add more than one Bootstrap template without affecting one over the other in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

For example, adding a bootstrap template to the admin is different from the bootstrap template for visitors.When adding more than one style according to the template, one of them affects the other, and its components are destroyed ,I added a Dashboard template to the admin whose style and files are different from the template files of the visitors, so the templates were destroyed

Answer (score 0):

I theory, nothing prevents you from using different css template depending on the route you are in your angular application.
But could you precise how exactly you use your "template" in your app ?
One way would be to define a `host` component for each route you want to define admin and visitor.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: VisitorsComponent,
        children: [... lazy loading routes]
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [... lazy loading routes]
    }
]
```

These routes allow you to define a top level component that will use either one of your templates.

I hope this could help you.
For more content on how routes help you handle use cases, check this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QgcMLAmm1s

Cheers